# perl ssh script to multiple hosts using alias

Tags: linux, perl, bash, ssh

I am trying to find out how to shorten my login of multiple SSH servers(Never the same one twice). There is several internet links to do it with the hostname built into the script. I require to enter a different hostname each time, I am trying to setup some sort of script to run an alias 'ssh hostname' with the same username, and same password, to different hostname after the script name. If needed I can call the script from PHP if required.

Just not having to manually enter the shh commandline, or enter the username manually each time would help alot.

**Current linux Alias doesn't work:**

```
alias sar='echo "message";ssh root@'
```

**Commandline:**

```
sar hostname1

ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
```

**Cannot use:**

```
Expect

SSH Key Authentication
```

Comment: I typed 'ssh' and read the command options, I changed alias to

**Alias**
alias sar='echo "message";ssh -l root'


And it works pretty good. Thanks to @Android user for editing code lines

Comment: Anyone who can read command history will see usernames which is a mild compromise of security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why about defining a function in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile:

```
function sar
{
   ssh root@$1
}
```

Alternative: configuring the default user for all your ssh or for a list or domain through ~/.ssh/config?

```
 Host *
     User root
 Host *.myDomain.com
     User root
```